SvelteKit Sub-Routes Conflict With Each Other
I'm building a SvelteKit app where the user can browse through media files based on categories and sub-categories, as well as having pagination to prevent too many files from being displayed at once. The routing hierarchy (inside src/routes) used to be like this and had no errors:
browse
    [category]
        [page]
            +page.svelte
        [subcategory]
            [fileName]
                +page.svelte

But then I add an additional route:
browse
    [category]
        [page]
            +page.svelte
        [subcategory]
            [fileName]
                +page.svelte
            [page]
                +page.svelte

After adding the [page] route to [subcategory], I get the following error when trying to run the project: The "/browse/[category]/[subcategory]/[fileName]" and "/browse/[category]/[subcategory]/[page]" routes conflict with each other. I tried commenting out all the code inside the files, but the same error occurs.
Why do [fileName] and [page] inside [subcategory] conflict while [subcategory] and [page] inside [category] don't conflict? And how can I make the former not conflict with each other while still being able to both include the subcategory and page number in the URL? Thanks in advance!

The original setup does not conflict because the number of provided parameters allows inference of which route is being used.
/browse/a/b   | has to be in [page]
/browse/a/b/c | has to be in in [subcategory] - there is a [fileName]

There are other ways to include things in the URL, for something like paging you could consider using a query parameter (?page=1) instead of a route parameter. (These parameters can be accessed/manipulated via the searchParams property of URLs.)
